# Angular resource query not recognised as array

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have a resource to access my stores location

```
appServices.factory('Store', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/backend/store',
        {},
        {
            'query': { method:'GET', isArray:true}
        });
}]);
```

I try to display this stores location in an ng-repeat. I have this issue in my controller:

```
// does not work
this.stores = Store.query({});
// works correctly
this.stores = ["Paris","Lyon","Marseille","Nantes"];
```

The webservice returns: 
["Paris","Lyon","Marseille","Nantes"]

Am I missing something?

I am using Angular 1.3.9

Comment: Well, does it? What does the Store.query({}) results actually look like, if not an array?

Comment: The ng-repeat does not print anything.

Comment: You can do better than that. ng-repeat not doing anything means it could be null, or an object, or a number of other things. Put a console.log after the query statement.

Comment: Found the issue: the code is correct. It is actually the angular-bootstrap-select component which is not working correctly and does not print an updated list of options.